Tokens randomly sent to a mev bot address
Last night I had some erc20 tokens transferred from my wallet to a mev bot address without my knowledge. It shows it being approved for trading and then two separate transactions of them taking tokens. I'm wondering how this could have happened if I'm not connected to any third party apps that I'm aware of.
Transaction hash of swaps from my wallet to mev bot address
0x3c666b092f32aaecf438ae36cf698b7b626431fd1fec867806cf7967474e301c
0x03d27072e679e1751da24c4df7ed9eeeb939434f61f12f7a88d120e956d91244
Transaction hash of BITCOIN being approved for trading. Which I don't remember approving.
0x9dc40b6acd3f191488f7cf6f4ee18842aa698449b7a3077d78d6d82020c73f6c
I created a new wallet and transferred everything out of this one. If anyone has any idea that would be appreciated.
Thanks

you might have written your private key in some scammy website
